# What zone does IE use to render local content?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've got a start page on my hard drive that uses (among other things) some local javascript and flash objects.  Every time I start IE and navigate to it, I have to clear the "content blocked" notification and allow the content.  I'd like to update my security settings to allow this content on the page; I'm quite sure that I trust it.

My question is, what zone does IE render this content in?  (IE9 in my case, but if it's different for other versions that's useful information as well.)  The status bar doesn't show a zone at all, and I would prefer not to go changing my zones around without at least some direction about where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally anything that doesn't end in a domain name is considered Local Intranet zone.  You can force other sites into that zone or the trusted zone by specifying them in the Internet Options security tab